# reCaptcha Enterprise error in ReactJS - grecaptcha.enterprise.render is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, recaptcha

I am trying to integrate Google reCaptcha Enterprise in my ReactJS application. I am following their guide and trying to explicitly load and render CheckBox challenge as below.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const onReCaptchaLoaded = () => {
      console.log("Inside callback...");
      console.log("window.grecaptcha object =");
      console.log(JSON.stringify(window.grecaptcha));
      window.grecaptcha.enterprise.render("reCaptcha_Enterprise_element", {
        sitekey: "<my-sitekey>",
      });
      setCaptchaLoaded(true);
    };

    const loadRecaptcha = (callback) => {
      const existingScript = document.getElementById("reCaptchaEnterprise");
      console.log("existingScript");
      console.log(existingScript);
      if (!existingScript) {
        console.log("Creating new script");

        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src =
          "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=explicit";
        script.id = "reCaptchaEnterprise";
        script.async = true;
        script.defer = true;
        console.log(script);
        console.log("Injecting script...");
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        script.addEventListener("load", () => {
          console.log("Script Loaded...");
          if (callback) callback();
        });
      }
      if (existingScript && callback) {
        console.log("Script already exists running callback...");
        callback();
      }
    };

    loadRecaptcha(onReCaptchaLoaded);
  }, []);
```

But the code failed  with the error **grecaptcha.enterprise.render is not a function**

Upon further inspection in console I found this is happening. After script loaded and load event fired the **enterprise** key is coming as blank and after some time only it is getting populated!! See below.

[image]

How can I correctly load and call the render method to initialize the CAPTCHA?

Comment: Just a thought, try turning off async / defer.

Comment: I am encountering this as well, but it is intermittent.  Removing async/defer did not help.  Were you able to correct?

Comment: @StinkyTowel True...! Even I tried all possible methods like removing async/defer and even i put the script tag directly on index.html...even then sometimes intermittently library loading issue was there..finally I managed to got it work without fail with some quick-and-dirty manual polling kind of code that check if object came to life with setInterval .. only that actually worked for me...